# Is the set of uniformly bounded nondecreasing functions on $[0,1]$ compact in any metric?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, compactness, monotone-functions

I am considering the set of nondecreasing functions defined on $[0,1]$. These functions are bounded by known constant $M$. Is this set of functions compact in any metric?

I am interested if there are some well known results in the corresponding literature on this on how to choose a metric (or topology) to obtain compactness of this set. I don't know infinite-dimensional analysis that well, I would not know where to look.

Comment: What about the topology of pointwise convergence? Isn't the set of increasing functions $[0,1]\to [-M,M]$ closed in $\mathbb R^{[0,1]}$? Then it will be compact by Tychonov.

Comment: @jochen the topological space is compact. But, is it metrizable?

Comment: No, it's not metrizable.

Comment: Any set whose cardinal is that of $\mathbb R$, such as your set ot functions, can be a compact metric space under some metric. But I expect you want a metric that has some algebraic or analytic relationship with the   the functions.

Comment: @user254665 Yes, it wold be nice to have a metric that is easily interpretable.